# Visualisation of Tree Hierarchy in HTML

Tags: recursion, treeview, visualization, data-visualization, tree-traversal

I am looking of inspiration for doing interaction design on a hierachy/tree structure. (products with a number of subproducts, rules that apply for selecting subproducts).

I want to have a tree where there is a visible connection between sub-nodes and their parent node. And i also want to visualize which rules that apply for selecting them.

Typical rules:

- mandatory: select only one of one sub-product
- optional: select 0 or more of several subproducts
- mutual exclusive: select only one of several subproducts

I hope you get the idea.

I am looking for any inspiration in this area. Any suggestions, examples, tips are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several:

- http://thejit.org/
- http://www.jsviz.org/blog/
- http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

If you are willing to use something other than html/javascript, [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) is an excellent library for Adobe Flash.

Comment: Those Protovis examples are just incredibly beautiful. I could study them for hours. Thanks for pointing me to them. 

Back to my question, there are some examples that could perhaps fit to the products/subproducts structure: Sunburst or Icicle both represent hierachy. But none visualize the rules perspective. How to visualize that some products are mandatory, others optional, and others again are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Can you give an example?  Are you saying a user chooses a make of a car and then has choices for so many mutually exclusive models and then has mutually exclusive choices of automatic vs manual and then has mutually exclusive choices for the color of the car, etc...  Then they have the optional choices of DVD player, GPS, etc...?  Is that the use case?  Who is the user?  Consumers?  Marketing people? Engineers?

Comment: Yes, the car example is pretty good, actually. (let's for now ignore the mandatory selections as one engine, four tyres, etc. ). Apart from mandatory selections, there are the optional as you mention. And also some that are mutually exclusive. In your example automatic vs manual shift. The product tree I try to visualize is more hierachical, so selections come into subproducts at any depth. So on each tree node, I really need something indicating the kind of selection. (maybe 'select 0..2' or similar on the tree node)

Comment: Just adding text such as 'select 0..2', 'optional', 'choose 1' may be reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Infoviz library for such scenario (here's the [demo](http://thejit.org/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html)). You could use distinct node colors for different selection rules together with some textual description, although it wouldn't be very intuitive at first.

Default tree orientation is horizontal, which may look odd, but makes sense when you add textual node names of variable length.